# Using Javascript To Click Multiple Links In Same Class But With Delay Between Each Different Link Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function(){
    window.location.href = $('.links').attr('href');
});
```

The Class Name is "links" and there are many links under it,how do i add a delay to each link click and not have the script click the same link again and again?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {
  // Grab all links into a wrapped set.
  var $links = $('.link');
  // Start with the first link at index 0 in the wrapped set.
  var linkNum = 0;
  // Specify our delay time.
  var delay = 1; // seconds

  // Setup a click handler on all our links.
  $links.click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    console.log($this.text() + ' clicked.');
    $this.css({ color: '#f00' });

    // After our delay, click the next link.
    setTimeout(function () {
      ++linkNum;
      if (linkNum < $links.length) {
        $links.eq(linkNum).click();
      } else {
        linkNum = 0;
        console.log("All links clicked.");
      }
    }, delay * 1000);
  });

  $('button').click(function () {
    $links.eq(0).click();
  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/WvzXbQ?editors=101